# Set properties on collection of List<T> when adding to List<T>

Tags: c#

I have a need for setting public properties on a collection of List based on the properties of T.  Here's what I mean:

```
public class Item
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
public class ItemCollection
{
    public decimal HighestPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal LowestPrice { get; set; }

    private List<Item> _collection;

    public List<Item> Collection
    {
        get => _collection;
        set
        {
            _collection = value;

            // Setting HighestPrice and LowestPrice
            if (HighestPrice < value.Price)
                HighestPrice = value.Price;

            if (LowestPrice > value.Price)
                LowestPrice = value.Price;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to extract the property of `value.Price` as `value` is actually a List.  I've tried various incarnations such as `value.First().Price` but it turns out that `value` always has a count of zero (go figure).

How can I pull the `Price` of the `Item` when I add it to the collection so I can track the highest and lowest prices?  This example assumes that `Item`(s) are all the same object but have differing prices.

Comment: You have to either iterate over the collection (for / foreach / etc) and find the price that way OR you a lambda expression like Max / Min. That said this type `ItemCollection` would be better of just being removed, once you learn how to use the built in linq expressions finding the min/max becomes trivial.

Comment: Because `value` isn't an `Item` it's a `List<Item>`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I've tried iterating over it with Foreach but the values HighestPrice and LowestPrice never get set...

Comment: You can just get the highest and lowest price when that property is accessed, rather than setting it when the collection changes: `public decimal HighestPrice => _collection?.Max(item => item.Price) ?? 0;` and `public decimal LowestPrice => _collection?.Min(item => item.Price) ?? 0;` If you don't want the overhead of calculating it each time, then in your setter for the collection you can just do something like `LowestPrice = Math.Min(LowestPrice, value.Min(item => item.Price));` and `HighestPrice = Math.Max(HighestPrice, value.Max(item => item.Price));`

Comment: You also might want to make the `set` private for those two properties (i.e. `public decimal HighestPrice { get; private set; }`) so the client can't change them.

Comment: @RufusL In that case `set` can be removed completely, I don't see how it could get implemented anyway, so it should be a read-only property.

Comment: @RayKoopa In the second case I mentioned (where the properties are calculated and set in the setter for the collection), the `set` would need to exist, but should be `private`. It could be implemented like: `public List<Item> Collection
        {
            get { return _collection; }
            set
            {
                _collection = value;

                LowestPrice = Math.Min(LowestPrice, value?.Min(item => item.Price) ?? 0);
                HighestPrice = Math.Max(HighestPrice, value?.Max(item => item.Price) ?? 0);
            } }`

Comment: @RufusL I see; that would not cover changes in the `Item` instances then, though.

Comment: @RayKoopa Yes, you're right! It should be a calculated field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to actually calculate `HighestPrice` and `LowestPrice` when getting their values instead of making them auto-implemented properties with no further logic behind them. Given you store your items in `Collection` (which can in turn can become an auto-property), it could look like this (but shouldn't, read below):

```
public class Item
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class ItemCollection
{
    public decimal HighestPrice
    {
        get
        {
            decimal maxPrice = decimal.MinValue;
            foreach (Item item in Collection)
            {
                if (item.Price > maxPrice)
                    maxPrice = item.Price;
            }
            return maxPrice;
        }
    }

    public decimal LowestPrice
    {
        get
        {
            decimal minPrice = decimal.MaxValue;
            foreach (Item item in Collection)
            {
                if (item.Price < minPrice)
                    minPrice = item.Price;
            }
            return minPrice;
        }
    }

    public List<Item> Collection { get; set; }
}
```

However, you can solve this much more elegant by using Linq, removing the need to even create a class `ItemCollection` and simply use a `List<Item>` instead. For example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; // Ensure to have this at the top of your source to access Linq methods.

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
            // Fill list here...

            // Use Linq Max and Min functions.
            // You pass the property to calculate the minimum and maximum from 
            // as x => x.Price (where x would represent an Item currently being
            // compared against another by Linq behind the scenes).
            decimal highestPrice = items.Max(x => x.Price);
            decimal lowestPrice = items.Min(x => x.Price);
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What Linq then does is iterate through your list "behind the scenes", compare the property of each element you passed in between instances (e.g. `Price` of each `Item` instance), and return the result.

You can see that the only thing you need to really define here then is the `Item` class which you've got already.

Linq has a lot of such operations which you can execute on lists (and other enumerable sources like arrays too). As soon as you add the `using System.Linq` statement to the top of your source, you can see all those operations in the auto-complete of your list variable.

Comment: Why not `public decimal HighestPrice => Collection.Max(x => x.Price);` and `public decimal LowestPrice => Collection.Min(x => x.Price)`? :) To the OP - one thing to mention - `Collection` can be null and it would throw `NullReferenceException`, use safe coding techniques or even better - initialize `Collection` from constructor.

Comment: Also, this code is not working. `LowestPrice` will return 0 for collection of [1.0m, 2.0m, 3.0m]. Initial value should be max possible value :)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Please give me time to write sample code and explain usage, I'm not as fast as comments :)

Comment: @RayKoopa Great answer!  I think this is just the trick.  I knew about Linq but hadn't considered it for some reason - old habits I guess :)

Comment: @ScottReeves Don't worry, if you start to think in lists rather than classes, you will start seeing Linq's advantages (even though the syntax may take some time to fully comprehend at first).